# Mypy reports two identical typings has incompatible

Tags: python, python-3.x, mypy

I am using `ParamSpec` and `Concatenate` to type hint callables.

Here's the code

```
from collections.abc import Callable
from typing import Concatenate, Generic, ParamSpec, TypeVar

T0 = TypeVar("T0")

P1 = ParamSpec("P1")
T1 = TypeVar("T1")


class TestClass(Generic[T0]):
    def __init__(self, obj: T0, method: Callable[Concatenate[T0, P1], T1]) -> None:
        self.obj = obj
        self.method = method


P2 = ParamSpec("P2")
T2 = TypeVar("T2")


def test_function(func: Callable[P2, T2], *args: P2.args, **kwargs: P2.kwargs) -> T2:
    return func(*args, **kwargs)


t = TestClass(1, lambda i: i)

print(test_function(t.method, t.obj))
```

And the mypy errors:

```
file.py:26: error: Argument 1 to "test_function" has incompatible type "Callable[[int, **P1], T1]"; expected "Callable[[int, **P1], T1]"
file.py:26: error: Argument 2 to "test_function" has incompatible type "int"; expected "[int, **P1.args]"
```

What I'm trying to do is storing a function that must accept `T0` as first arg and passing it to a function that accepts anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you've lost `P1` and `T1` information after `__init__`, it is not attached to your class. Using them in `Generic` solves the issue:

```py
from collections.abc import Callable
from typing import Concatenate, Generic, ParamSpec, TypeVar

T0 = TypeVar("T0")

P1 = ParamSpec("P1")
T1 = TypeVar("T1")


class TestClass(Generic[T0, P1, T1]):
    def __init__(self, obj: T0, method: Callable[Concatenate[T0, P1], T1]) -> None:
        self.obj = obj
        self.method = method


P2 = ParamSpec("P2")
T2 = TypeVar("T2")


def test_function(func: Callable[P2, T2], *args: P2.args, **kwargs: P2.kwargs) -> T2:
    return func(*args, **kwargs)

def mth(i: int) -> int:  # Instead of lambda, to avoid unexpected Any
    return i
    
    
t = TestClass(1, mth)

print(test_function(t.method, t.obj))
```

([playground](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&gist=349b0014ed5ecd7a0df1b5f366ac7b77)).

Strictly speaking, you could expect `mypy` to type `method` after resolving type vars, but it does never happen (in any context). It would lead to ambiguous resolution: should it be `Callable[[int], int]`? `Callable[[T0], int]`? `Callable[[T0], T0]`? Something else? (I cannot even say which of these I'd personally prefer, it is very hard to define non-ambiguous, you'll have to keep in mind Generic/Protocol, bound typevars in `Callable` itself and in outer method, etc.)